# Lua Read File and Write to New File

Tags: file, lua

I need to copy a file and change the extension from .seq to mid (without using shell commands)
This works

```
file = io.open(source_filename, "rb")
source_content = file:read("*all")
file = io.open(source_filename ..".mid", "wb")
file:write(source_content)
file:close()
```

and I get `Song.seq.mid`
but I would like `Song seq.mid`

if I do a

```
source_filename = string.gsub(source_filename, ".seq", ".mid")
file = io.open(source_filename, "wb")
```

then file has a nil value `file:write(source_content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `source_filename` before opening the file for writing: `source_filename = source_filename:gsub("seq$", "mid")`. This will replace `seq` at the end of the filename with `mid`, achieving the desired effect.

Comment: thanks it was the $ that did it `source_filename = string.gsub(source_filename, ".seq$", " seq .mid")`